# Unexpected Character $ - Java Binding error

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I am trying java binding to a Xamarin forms project and the jar contains class name having $ and also variable names with $. I am getting "Unexpected Character $" error. I am trying to solve it by editing the metadata.xml file. It seems that I am doing it wrong, please check the following entries,

For the class names containing $. I am using,

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.wed.therace']/class[@name='CarDetails$']" 
    name="obfuscated">false</attr>
```

for the variables containing $,

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.wed.therace']/class[@name='CarDetails$']/fie    ld[@name='machineParts$']" 
name="obfuscated">false</attr>
```

What is the correct way? I got this from https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I have never worked with Xamarin, but it seems it uses some XPaths and probably XSL transformation inside and dollar sign has special meaning in XSL, so try to escape it with `\$`.  
There is also some instructions on link you gave, refer to: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/#obfuscated

Comment: The `$` represents an anonymous inner class in Java. Thus you would need the full name such as `CarDetails${ClassName}` here. If you can upload a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can help you investigate these issues. *Note: I wrote portions of the docs referred to by Sergi*

Answer (score 0):

The sample you tried disables obfuscation for certain types or members. But `$` doesn't necessary mean the code has been obfuscated. Here's the common flow for you of what to do in such cases:

1. Navigate to the error source to see the generated output C# code. In your error message you'll most likely see something like `Error: obj/Debug/src/234.cs (30, 50)`. Look into this file and see what happens in it on line 30. In your case you'll see a field containing `$` in its name which leads to compilation error. Pay attention there is a generator comment line in this file starting with `// Metadata.xml XPath ... path="/api/package[@name=...]"`, like this. You can just copy the `path="..."` part to use it for configurations in manifest.xml.
2. Look into generated `api.xml` file located in `obj/Debug` (or `obj/Release` depending or your current config). Try looking for the member definition you have issue in. You should be able to find your field, method or another member there with all its attributes like `static`, `deprecated`, `obfuscated` etc. That's what you can affect with metadata transformations.

Now depending on your situation try one of the following:

3. If you don't need this type or member in your code, just get rid of it by using `remove-node` metadata element. Get the `path` value from the generated sources as described above. Remember you can either remove the error member or the whole type if you don't need it.
4. If you do need this member, define a rename transformation in metadata like this: `<attr path="<copied_from_sources>" name="managedName">ValidNameHere</attr>`.

Sometimes you'll need to clean the `obj` folder to make changes applied. Usually it works correct though.