# Binding .AAR that contains Realm Android Xamarin

Tags: java, android, xamarin, realm, aar

I'm trying to bind an AAR library to a Xamarin android project.

Using jar2xml as AndroidClassParser in the binding project the main issue that i have is the fact that the AAR library contains a realm DB, realm creates some proxy interfaces that contains some variables with a $ inside the variable name, this result in this error

> CS1056 Unexpected character '$'

instead using class-parse as AndroidClassParser result in other error such as this

> CS0111 Already defines a member called 'Translate' with the same
>   parameter types

this is the java code that raise the CS0111 error

```
public interface ModelTranslator<T extends DomainClass, S> {

    S translate(T from);

    void translate(T from, S to);

    T translate(S from);

    void translate(S from, T to);

}
```

is there a way to fix this?

> EDIT: I have fixed most of the issue inside Metadata.xml

the only things that remains to fix is a class that extends `Comparator`
converting this class result in this error.

> CS0534  C# does not implement inherited abstract member

but the class implement everything that is present inside `Comparator`

Comment: What is the name of the library you're binding?

Comment: the library is not a public library

Comment: How can you fix these with the Metadata.xml?

Comment: Can anyone please tell which aar  is used in Realm for Xamarin Android Bindings?

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help you
[Unexpected Character $ - Java Binding error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975237/unexpected-character-java-binding-error)

> If you do need this member, define a rename transformation in metadata like this: " name="managedName">ValidNameHere.

And here some useful blog post that shows the troubleshooting for many Binding errors scenarios:
https://www.codepool.biz/binding-android-library-xamarin-disaster.html